# How to Sync a mysql local database to online(host) database in java Swing Application?

Tags: java, mysql, synchronization

I want to synchronize localhost mysql database and online mysql database in java pragramming...

Comment: Start with java code?

Answer (score 0):

There is this library. https://www.symmetricds.org/ However, I would recommend modifying your design to not need this type of setup. It is error prone at best.. We have used it in the past with moderate results. But you end up with a lot of synchronization errors you have to manually reconcile. It would be much better to code your local application to talk to the remote database directly.